# How to run artisan command schedule:run on hosting server? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, cpanel

I have a statusUpdate.php file in the xampp\htdocs\project\app\Console\Commands folder.

statusUpdate.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;


class statusUpdate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'status:update';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Update Job status daily';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    $affected = DB::table('jobs')->update(array('status' => 1));
}
}
```

I created it following the official Laravel documentation. After that, I added \App\Console\Commands\statusUpdate::class to the Kernel.php file located in xampp\htdocs\project\app\Console.

Here's the code from the Kernel.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\statusUpdate::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('status:update')
             ->everyFiveMinutes();
}
}
```

I then ran the following command using CMD on Windows:

> php artisan schedule:run

Now, it works fine on my local server. The status field in my jobs table updates correctly to 1.

However, when I deployed this project to shared hosting and set up a CRON job in cPanel, it didn't work. The CRON job command is:

`php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

In this hosted environment, the command isn't functioning. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @michael yes I added my path, /home/username/public_html/projectfolder/artisan schedule:run

Comment: What is the configuration of your server? Tell OS and whether you have installed the CRON

Comment: @Aditya Giri, server configuration means it is my shared hosting panel. yes OS already installed CRON.

Comment: I gave the answer below. Check that ones first

Comment: @AdityGiri,  
what is the different between my command php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 and your command php /var/www/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1! I already give my correct path in command

Comment: You should try setting the **complete absolute path** to your `php` interpreter as well in your cron job command: `/path/to/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`. You can get the absolute path to your `php` binary from the [PHP_BINDIR](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) reserved constant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well. I am giving you the answer as per what you have said.

> Cron job command is like this : `php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

The path should be locating the artisan file in the server. Like this:

Let's say your artisan file location is `/var/www/artisan`, then the simple answer could be do like this:

`php /var/www/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Just check if that works. Thank You!

**UPDATE**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYjI0.png]

This is how it should look like.

Comment: what is the different between my command php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 and your command php /var/www/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1! i already give my correct path in command.

Comment: Well both are same. Let's say that you are running a server with Linux Environment. `path/to/artisan` means that you are linking to something like `D:\xampp\path\to\artisan` and obviously that is not the thing that you are looking for. You are linking to a file that never existed there. It will definitely work if you change the filepath. Tell me your project root directory path and I will tell you the correct command that you should input.

Comment: /home/belogin/public_html/jobssite/ this my path and and I tried using this /home/belogin/public_html/jobssite/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 but not works.

Comment: Well I had a look at the documentation and the query should be like: `* * * * * php /home/belogin/public_html/jobssite/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: ok. when I give * * * * * php /home/belogin/public_html/jobssite/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 in command box. it show bad command can't install in cron :( because I already give time using another option.

Comment: Well sorry. In your cron jobs do something like what I say. I am uploading one pic.

Comment: Ok. But your instruction are very helpful for me.

Comment: When I add cron using URL and URL hit my method it works fine.

Comment: Great to hear that. Did my answer help?

Comment: And yeah using URL means in what way? If you can hit your URL, then there is a great chance to **hack** your website.

Comment: Mark as answer if that helped you!

Comment: Which Hosting Company Are You Using? In the pic

Answer (score 14):

This worked fine for me

```
/usr/local/bin/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the command from the cPanel server as

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xyz/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel 2>&1
```

This will keep all the logs in `/home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel`

```
Running scheduled command: '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' SyncAPIOrders:orders > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

In my case cron Job was not working, if you are about to schedule the command as once a day (i.e., 00:00) iff, same time is **not** reflected in a `$schedule->command();` object

If the commands were incorrect, I used to get this warning in my Email as

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'magickwand' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.37
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

In `Kernel.php` you should specify

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('SyncAPIOrders:orders')
               ->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
               ->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```