# How to run artisan command schedule:run on "hostgator shared" hosting server? (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have been trying for 2 days to set up a laravel command on hostgator shared hosting. I contacted with their support team but they are not giving coding issue support.
They said that i can set up min 15 mins cron on their shared hosting.
But i tested a cron that run in every 1 min: (for testing perpose)

```
*/1     *   *   *   *   php -q /home1/john/mydomain.com/cron.php
```

In that cron.php i wrote:

```
    <?php
$file = "cron.html";
if (!unlink($file))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $file");
  }

?>
```

This cron successfully deleted cron.html file if 
found in every min.
This test is success but i can't run cron on another domain where my laravel 5.7 app is present.

I tested my code on local:
When i run php artisan `php artisan schedule:run` , it run on local successfully.

I want to run migration on hostgator shared hosting. That's why i changed console/kernel.php file :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    \Log::info('cron worked');

    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();



    $schedule->command('migrate')
        ->everyMinute();
}
```

And i tried few cron on hostgator:

```
*/1     *   *   *   * 

/usr/bin/php /var/www/home1/john/domain.com/artisan schedule:run

/usr/local/bin/php  /home1/john/domain.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Also tried following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283517/how-to-run-artisan-command-schedulerun-on-hosting-server-laravel):

Please provide me your tested solution if you do this on hostgator shared hosting.